# trouble invoking a Jquery dialog box on a 'parent' page

Tags: jquery, user-interface, iframe, dialog, parent

I am having a trouble invoking a Jquery dialog box on a 'parent' page.

I'm calling the dialog 'open' from a dynamically loaded page within an iFrame on the 'parent' page.

The showDialog button is on that dynamic IFrame form.

I'm using `#divId` as the placeholder div, and `#modalIframeId1` is where the dynamic form gets loaded via `src='AddLead.aspx'` for instance.

If I put `#divId` & `#modalIframeId1` on the master page for the popup form it works, but I want a 'generic' divId on the parent page, so the dialog popups up in the parent page, not on the form in the IFrame - it's too small for some dialogs I need to call.

Essentially there is this "parent level" I need to address so when I set the options & call with code like this, it will work:

```
$('#divId').dialog('option', 'height', vHeight);

$('#divId').dialog('option', 'width', intWidth);   

$('#divId').dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
$('#divId').dialog('open');
```

I have tried various `parent()` type calls, but can't seem to be able to set and open the dialog on the parent page from the child page.

Thanks,

Charles

Answer (score 2):

Give a try for this one

```
var dialogplaceholder = window.parent.$("#divId");
dialogplaceholder.dialog('open');
```

The code is self-explainatory, select element of id= #divId from the parent window and use it as a placeholder to open a dialog box.

Hope this helps.